# Efficient Way to specific combinations from string

Tags: php, combinations

So I have a phrase like this:

```
one_two_three_four
```

.. and for clarity, it could be something like this too:

```
one_two_three_four_five_six_seven_eight_nine_ten_eleven_twelve
```

.. but for purposes of brevity, I am just going to use this one as an example:

```
one_two_three_four
```

From the string, I want to create the following keywords

```
one
one_two
one_two_three
two
two_three
two_three_four
three
three_four
four
```

I am looking for the most efficient way (in PHP) to parse out strings like this (some will be much larger).

I can get this far:

```
$keyword = explode('_', $string);
```

So now I have an array like this:

```
one
two
three
four
```

I am stuck on how to get from the original string into the variants.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First thing you need to explode the string by `_`

```
$str = 'one_two_three_four_five_six';
$array = explode('_', $str);
```

Add an empty array to store result there

```
$result = [];
```

Define a **recursive function** that takes an array, implode array values, remove last element and recall the same array **until** length is 0

```
function visitArray($array, &$result) {
    if(count($array) == 0) //Check if length is 0 (Stop executing)
        return;
    $result[] = implode('_', $array); //Implode array values
    return visitArray(array_slice($array, 0, count($array) -  1), $result); //Remove last element and call again the same function
}
```

So if you pass `[1, 2, 3]` to **visitArray** you will have
`1_2_3`, `1_2`, `1` in the result array.

Now you need a secondary function to call `visitArray` with a new position,

That means, if we have this array `[1, 2, 3]`

we need to call **visitArray** `[1,2,3]`, `[2,3]`, `[3]`

So we define a function with simple for loop to iterate around array values, and each time we call **visitArray()** and we ignore the called once by using array_slice with `position` variable.

```
function callVisit($array, &$result, $position = 0) {
    for($i = 0; $i < count($array); $i++)
        visitArray(array_slice($array, $position++, count($array) - 1), $result);
}
```

**Update:**
If you need to remove the position param you could replace the forloop with list as below:

```
function callVisit($array, &$result) {
    while (list(,$v) = each($array)) 
    { 
        visitArray($array, $result);
        array_shift($array); //Remove first element
    } 
}
```

So you need to call callVisit() by passing two params, the array, result array (where result should be stored)

```
callVisit($array, $result);
```

**Full code:**

```
<?php

$str = 'one_two_three_four_five_six';

$array = explode('_', $str);

$result = [];


function callVisit($array, &$result, $position = 0) {
    for($i = 0; $i < count($array); $i++) 
        visitArray(array_slice($array, $position++, count($array) - 1), $result);
}

function visitArray($array, &$result) {
    if(count($array) == 0)
        return;
    $result[] = implode('_', $array);
    return visitArray(array_slice($array, 0, count($array) -  1), $result);
}


callVisit($array, $result);

echo "<pre>", json_encode($result, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT), "</pre>";
```

Comment: Why should the OP try this? A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Comment: @JayBlanchard you're right. but still seems my answer still incorrect according to his **missing** requirements.

Comment: He has no missing requirements as far as I can see.

Comment: Seems we are talking about range from ```1 to (N - 1)``` instead of ```1 to N```

Comment: It looks that way, but look at his desired result again. Do you see *`two_four`*?